# I want to write this method just Once and call it multiple times for assigning the value for Various TextView

Tags: java, android, methods

```
private void getClubTiming(TextView txtClubTime) {

    TextView txtClub = txtClubTime;
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    CalendarHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    CalendarMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            (view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
                if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                    hourOfDay += 12;
                    format = "am";
                } else if (hourOfDay == 12) {
                    format = "pm";
                } else if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                    hourOfDay -= 12;
                    format = "pm";
                } else {
                    format = "am";
                }
                Log.i("@sandy","ClubTiming: "+txtClub);
                if (txtClub!=null){
                    txtClub.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d" + format, hourOfDay, minute));


                }


            }, CalendarHour, CalendarMinute, false);
    timepickerdialog.show();
}
```

As I just Want to call this method OnClickListener always for assigning the TimePicker value, but giving me Null Pointer Exception the Exception is `txtClub.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d" + format, hourOfDay, minute));`
I have the Problem in Setting the Value for TextView. Please Help Me there.. Thank You.

Comment: Show me the code where are you calling this?

Comment: getTxtFromSunday().setOnClickListener(view -> getClubTiming(txtClubTime));  I m calling it from same class

Comment: where do you bind you textView ? It may be helpful if you post whole activity class

Comment: check the value of `txtClubTime` it must be null

Comment: yes txtClubTime is Null...How to assign the Time to it Before

Comment: Thanks Sandeep Let me check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Initialization all data in the `initView` method

Try this in your code .

```
public class SignUpSecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private EditText txtFrom, txtTo;
private Calendar calendar;
private TimePickerDialog timepickerdialog;
private int CalendarHour, CalendarMinute;
private String format;
private TextView txtClubTime,txtFromSunday,txtToSunday,txtFromMonday,txtToMonday;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_second);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    initView();
    getTxtFromSunday().setOnClickListener(view -> getClubTiming(txtClubTime));
}

private void initView() {
    txtClubTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClubTime);
    txtFromSunday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFromSunday);
    txtToSunday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToSunday);
    txtFromMonday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFromMonday);
    txtToMonday = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToMonday);
}

private void getClubTiming(TextView txtClubTime) {

    TextView txtClub = txtClubTime;
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    CalendarHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    CalendarMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            (view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
                if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                    hourOfDay += 12;
                    format = "am";
                } else if (hourOfDay == 12) {
                    format = "pm";
                } else if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                    hourOfDay -= 12;
                    format = "pm";
                } else {
                    format = "am";
                }
                Log.i("@sandy","ClubTiming: "+txtClub);
                if (txtClub!=null){
                    txtClub.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d" + format, hourOfDay, minute));
                    Log.i("@sandy","ClubTiming- "+txtClub);
                }

                Log.i("@sandy", "Time: " + String.format("%02d:%02d" + format, hourOfDay, minute));
            }, CalendarHour, CalendarMinute, false);
    timepickerdialog.show();
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the IDs of the textviews in the oncreate of your app, it won't hurt, Also you can assign the onclick listeners in 2 ways,

1. implement onclick listener
2. use onclick in xml

Now create your method and call it at anypoint you want.

From activity:

```
yourMethod();
```

From Fragment:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity).yourMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because you didn't assign anything to your txtClubTime,
Change your code like this and tell me does this is helpful or not

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_second);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//Make a textView in xml and bind it .
TextView txtClubTime=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtClubTime);

        getTxtFromSunday().setOnClickListener(view -> getClubTiming(txtClubTime));
    }

    private void getClubTiming(TextView txtClubTime) {

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        CalendarHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        CalendarMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        timepickerdialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                (view, hourOfDay, minute) -> {
                    if (hourOfDay == 0) {
                        hourOfDay += 12;
                        format = "am";
                    } else if (hourOfDay == 12) {
                        format = "pm";
                    } else if (hourOfDay > 12) {
                        hourOfDay -= 12;
                        format = "pm";
                    } else {
                        format = "am";
                    }
                    Log.i("@sandy","ClubTiming: "+txtClubTime);
                    if (txtClub!=null){
                        txtClubTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d" + format, hourOfDay, minute));
                        Log.i("@sandy","ClubTiming- "+txtClub);

                    }

                    Log.i("@sandy", "Time: " + String.format("%02d:%02d" + format, hourOfDay, minute));
                }, CalendarHour, CalendarMinute, false);
        timepickerdialog.show();
    }




    private TextView getTxtFromSunday() {
        return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFromSunday);
    }

    private TextView getTxtToSunday() {
        return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToSunday);
    }

    private TextView getTxtFromMonday() {
        return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtFromMonday);
    }

    private TextView getTxtToMonday() {
        return (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtToMonday);
    }


    }
```

Just add this like inside your method :

```
this.txtClubTime=new TextView(this);
```

Comment: I m getting the value for Only single TextView, But what if i want to assign it for another TextView.I have total 14 TextViews and i want to create this method only once, but can't assign the value to it as setText

Comment: Ok OK for that You have to make a dynamic textView So that it will create each time when you called the method

Comment: Take a textview and make a swtich case and on the basis of choice assign textView different text